# Ellipsis operator Java equivalence in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, variadic-functions, ellipsis

In Java, it is possible to do something like this: `void function(Url... urls)`. It makes possible to use 1..n urls. The question is if it is possible to do the same thing with Kotlin.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Kotlin reference (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html):

> **Variable number of arguments (Varargs)**
>
> A parameter of a function (normally the last one) may be marked with
>   vararg modifier:
>
> ```
> fun <T> asList(vararg ts: T): List<T> {
>     val result = ArrayList<T>()
>     for (t in ts) // ts is an Array
>         result.add(t)
>     return result
> }
> ```
>
> allowing a variable number of arguments to be passed to the function:
>
> ```
> val list = asList(1, 2, 3)
> ```
>
> Inside a function a vararg-parameter of type T is visible as an array
>   of T, i.e. the ts variable in the example above has type Array.

Beware of a difference with Java: in Java you can pass an array as single parameter, while in Kotlin you must explicitly unpack the array, so that every
array element becomes a separate argument. But you can do it by simply putting the * character before the corresponding argument:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = listOf("args: ", *args)
    println(list)
}
```

(See how it lets you combine the values from an array and some fixed values in a single call, which is not allowed in Java).

Answer (score 7):

The solution is with `vararg` and the it is possible to iterate over the parameter.

```
private fun areValidFields(vararg fields: String) : Boolean{
    return fields.none { it.isNullOrEmpty() || it.isBlank() }
}
```